# migrating AngularJS to Angular 5

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

We are currently migrating our ui-library from AngularJS to Angular 5.

I have had a look at one of our components but unsure what to do with $scope and how to migrate this into card.component.ts

From my research, I understand 'this' replaces $scope but not entirely sure how to implement it into the card.component.ts file.

```
$scope.vmOptions = {
    location: 'http://www.google.com'
};
```

`

**Current AngularJS code:**

**card-demo.controller.ts**

```
import { Module } from '../../../module';
import "./card-demo.template.html";

Module.register.config(['ComponentRegistry', (ComponentRegistry) => {
  ComponentRegistry.push({
    name: "card",
    title: "Card",
    description: "Card"
  });
}]);

Module.register.controller('testCardDemo', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
  $scope.vmOptions = {
    location: 'http://www.google.com'
  };
}]);
```

**card-demo.template.html**

```
<div ng-controller="testCardDemo">
  <test-card data-test-id="default-card">
    <test-card-title>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </test-card-title>
    <test-card-content>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    </test-card-content>
    <test-card-link>
      <a href="{{vmOptions.location}}" class="test-active-link"></a>
    </test-card-link>
  </test-card>
</div>
```

---

**Angular 5 code:**

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-demo',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})
export class CardDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**card.component.html**

```
<h2>Card Component</h2>
<rt-card testId="test-card">
    <rt-card-title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</rt-card-title>
    <rt-card-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</rt-card-content>
    <rt-card-footer><a href="{{location}}" class="rt-active-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></rt-card-footer>
</rt-card>
```

Comment: You must forget all the code in **Angular JS** because they aren't compatibles, my recomendation is look for all dependencies in `npm` or `yarn`, and create you card component in  angular from scratch. and take a look for [oficial angular tutorial.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare variable inside class with proper type so that error can be found at time of compilation, after declaration you can use that variable inside the class using `this` keyword.

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-demo',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})
export class CardDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  location: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.location = 'http://www.google.com'
  }
}
```

**card.component.html**

```
<h2>Card Component</h2>
<rt-card testId="test-card">
    <rt-card-title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</rt-card-title>
    <rt-card-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</rt-card-content>
    <rt-card-footer><a href="{{location}}" class="rt-active-link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></rt-card-footer>
</rt-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a ‘location’ variable inside the class and set ‘this.location = ‘path’ inside the ngOnInit() function.

You will be able to access the location variable inside the html like: {{location}}